# Вращение и запрет вращения части subview в xcode

Tags: xcode

Как разрешить части subview вращение, а части subview запретить в том числе и главному экрану.

наверно не очень развернутый вопрос:)
Необходимо чтобы первое (главное superview) не могло вращатьтся а вызванные из него subview могли.
Примеры как это сделать нашел. Но на практике не работают.
Например можно запретить вращение subview
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353789...n-for-a-subview

Например http://www.disalvotech.com/blog/app-develo...ation-solution/

Answer (score 1):

возможно вам поможет мой небольшой опыт : когда я решал проблему с автовращениями в своем приложении, добавил пару shouldAutorotate и supportedInterfaceOrientations во все вьюшки и контроллеры и в каждую добавил NSLog. Это позволило мне увидеть что shouldAutorotate в нужном месте просто не вызывается.

И, конечно, в свойствах проекта должны поддерживаться все ориентации, которые в проекте используются хотя бы один раз.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил ссылки
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353789/ios-disable-autorotation-for-a-subview
http://www.disalvotech.com/blog/app-development/iphone/ios-6-rotation-solution/